# passport local strategy simple access to two directories via static fail

Tags: javascript, express, passport-local

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/login'));
app.use('/public',  passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/nop.html' }));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
    function(req, res) {
        res.redirect('app.html');
    });

file struture ----
  app.js (node app)
  login
         index.html (login page)
  public
         app.html (client page)
```

HTTP://my-site/      shows login page. **works**

When I put **invalid** user/pass it redirects to self **works**

When I put **valid** user/pass in I get "Cannot GET /app.html"  **doesn't work**

I know it's an easy fix, but stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.

Since I had multiple dirs serving static files, I needed to specify which root I needed.

`app.get('/app.html', (req, res) => { res.sendFile('/public', { root: __dirname }); });`